# How much does column dtype affect to_csv() performance?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a dataframe with ~11.4 million rows and 140 columns. In trying to output to a gzip compressed CSV (it does need to be CSV, at least for now) I'm getting insanely slow disk write speeds, something like 50 kbps. Writing this particular dataframe to disk took 7 hours 5 minutes, which is untenable going forward. Could the dtypes of the columns cause such a slowdown? Maybe my hard drive is just failing? I'm inclined to believe that this is an I/O bottleneck and so the makeup of my dataframe doesn't much matter, is that correct?

I've written other similar datasets to disk (same columns, different time period for samples) and it wasn't as fast as I would like but not the slow speeds I'm seeing with my latest data.

The dtypes, if it matters, is:

```py
In [5]: Counter(df.dtypes.tolist()).most_common()
Out[5]: [(dtype('float64'), 90), (dtype('O'), 42), (dtype('int64'), 8)]
```

Comment: I don't see why the dtypes should cause your issue. You can always use timers and try different formats for a smaller sample of rows. The write-time should be linear to the amount of rows, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to output to CSV, so different formats aren't really an option. All else equal I would use hdf5, but that's not an option here.

Comment: What I actually was asking was how big time it would be to write, say.. 100 rows. Is it linear to your 11.4M?